# php displaying all db records in smarty tpl

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I want to create an array and assign it to smarty template to display all of my news. But the problem is it is only picking up the first row of data in the table, how can I fix this? It is only showing the first ever row and ther eis 4 rows in the database

I am using mysqli for db driver...

```
$newsArray = array();
        $row = autoLoader::getLibrary('database')->query("SELECT * FROM `cms_news`")->fetch_array();
            $newsArray[] = $row;

        $this->smarty->assign('website_news', $newsArray);
```

Then I display it using this code in the tpl

```
{section name=nr loop=$website_news} 
   {$website_news[nr].id} 
   {$website_news[nr].title} 
   {$website_news[nr].shortstory}<br /> 
{sectionelse} 
   <h1>No news found!</h1> 
{/section}
```

Comment: You can directly assign `$row` to `website_news`.

Comment: Check what you are getting inside $newsArray. `var_dump($newsArray);die;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$newsArray = autoLoader::getLibrary('database')->query("SELECT * FROM `cms_news`")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
$this->smarty->assign('website_news', $newsArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your template seems to be ok. The problem is with your date not being fully loaded as an array. This is a php (controller) side error. You can verify if your `print_r($newsArray);` contains full data.